# How to transfer an object from the registration form to the controller for writing to the database and assigning a role?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a common User class and its descendants with a specific role. How do I create an object in the registration controller, depending on the choice in the registration form? Can this be done via radio button and thymeleaf?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Transient
    private String matchingPassword;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String patronymic;
    private LocalDate birthday;
    private String hometown;
    private String number;
    private String mail;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private List<Role> roles;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Student")
@Table(name = "student", schema = "public")
public class Student extends User {

    private String studentIdNumber;
    private String groupNumber;
    private String academicPerformance;
    private String faculty;
    private String department;
    private long rating;

    @Builder
    public Student(Long id,
                   String username,
                   String password,
                   String matchingPassword,
                   String name,
                   String surname,
                   String patronymic,
                   LocalDate birthday,
                   String hometown,
                   String number,
                   String mail,
                   String studentIdNumber,
                   String groupNumber,
                   String academicPerformance,
                   String faculty,
                   String department,
                   List<Role> roles) {
        super(id, username, password, matchingPassword, name, patronymic, surname, birthday, hometown, number, mail, roles);
        this.studentIdNumber = studentIdNumber;
        this.groupNumber = groupNumber;
        this.academicPerformance = academicPerformance;
        this.faculty = faculty;
        this.department = department;
        this.rating = 0;
    }
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Director")
@Table(name = "director", schema = "public")
public class Director extends User {

    private String department;

    @Builder
    public Director(Long id,
                    String username,
                    String password,
                    String matchingPassword,
                    String name,
                    String surname,
                    String patronymic,
                    LocalDate birthday,
                    String hometown,
                    String number,
                    String mail,
                    String department,
                    List<Role> roles) {
        super(id,
                username,
                password,
                matchingPassword,
                name,
                surname,
                patronymic,
                birthday,
                hometown,
                number,
                mail,
                roles);
        this.department = department;
    }
}
```

The controller in which the object is created for writing to the database and defining the role:

```
    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        log.info("showRegistrationForm method called");
        model.addAttribute("newUser", new User());   <----- Creation of a specific object. How!?
        model.addAttribute("avatar", "default_avatar.png");
        model.addAttribute("username", "Unknown");

        return "registration";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added mapping where the user selects a role.